# How to return Map object from Cypress each?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, cypress

So, I write TAF to automate user cases using Cypress. I'm a novice in it.

I need to return from Cypress `each` command a `Map` with some values to use it in next command as input value.

In DOM there are some amount of `canvas` tags like this:

```
<canvas class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" width="256" height="256" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(613px, 246px, 0px); opacity: 1;"></canvas>
```

From `style` attribute I need to extract two coordinates, so, just transform value:

```
width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(613px, 246px, 0px); opacity: 1;
```

to

```
613 246
```

and set it like a key to Map object. And as value I need to set a buffer of encoded canvas data.

So, I add custom command like this:

```
function convertCanvasMatrixToPictureCommand() {
  Cypress.Commands.add('renderCanvasMatrixToPng', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, savePath) => {
    const bufferMap = new Map();
    cy.wrap(subject)
      .each(canvas => {
        Cypress.Blob.canvasToBlob(canvas.get(0))
          .then(blob => Cypress.Blob.blobToArrayBuffer(blob))
          .then(buff => {
            const coordinates = extract(canvas.attr('style'));
            const buffer = Buffer.from(buff);
            bufferMap.set(coordinates, buffer);
          });
      // and here in some way I need to return bufferMap obj
      // to use it as input data in next cypress task:
      })
      .task('mergeImages', { buffers: bufferMap, savePath: 'cypress/snapshots' });
  });
}
```

`mergeImages` task will proceed the map and using specified sorting, merge all canvases to a single `PNG` image.

But is it possible in some way to return this map from `each` command?

This `bufferMap` object valid only inside each command. But out of `each` it still empty

`cy.wprap()` also not resolve this issue. Or I use it incorrect...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems with the custom command

- to make sure you wait on the results of `.each()`, must return the promise created bt `Cypress.Blob.canvasToBlob()` chain.
- follow the `.each()` with a `.then()` to ensure completion, and return `bufferMap here.

Problems with `.task()`

- it does not like being called within the custom command, so call it after

  > CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
- it does not like a `Map()` object as a parameter, convert to a plain object

**Test**

```js
describe('leaflet', () => {

  it('processes', () => {

    Cypress.Commands.add('renderCanvasMatrixToPng', {prevSubject: true}, (subjects, savePath) => {
      const bufferMap = new Map();
      cy.wrap(subjects)
        .each((canvas, i) => {
          return Cypress.Blob.canvasToBlob(canvas.get(0))   // <- add return here
            .then(blob => Cypress.Blob.blobToArrayBuffer(blob))
            .then(buff => {
              var view = new Int8Array(buff);  // not sure why this is needed
              const buffer = Buffer.from(view);

              // get coords here
              const coords = 1000 + i // for purpose of demo
              bufferMap.set(coords, buffer)
            })
        })
        .then(_ => {                           // <- wait for previous to complete
          console.log('bufferMap inside command', bufferMap)  // [[Entries]]
                                                              //  0: {0 => Uint8Array(27209)}
                                                              //  1: {1 => Uint8Array(1179)}
          return bufferMap;
        })
    });

    cy.visit('http://cartodb.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer/example.html')

    cy.get('canvas').renderCanvasMatrixToPng().then(bufferMap => {
      console.log('bufferMap outside command', bufferMap)  // [[Entries]]
                                                           //    0: {1000 => Uint8Array(25218)}
                                                           //    1: {1001 => Uint8Array(1179)}
      const asObject = Object.fromEntries(bufferMap);
      cy.task('mergeImages', { buffers: asObject, savePath: 'cypress/snapshots' });
    })

  })
})
```

---

**Task for demo**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  ...
  on('task', {
    mergeImages(options) {
      const { buffers, savePath } = options;

      console.log('buffers', buffers);
      /* In terminal

        buffers {
          '1000': {
            type: 'Buffer',
            data: [
              137,  80,  78,  71,  13,  10,  26,  10,   0,   0,   0,  13,
              ... 33137 more items
            ]
          },
          '1001': {
            type: 'Buffer',
            data: [
              137,  80,  78,  71,  13,  10,  26,  10,   0,   0,   0,  13,
              ... 1079 more items
            ]
          }
        }
      */

      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

---

**Alternative command (my preference)**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('renderCanvasMatrixToPng', { prevSubject: true }, (subjects, savePath) => {
  const bufferPromises = Array.from(subjects).map(canvas => {
    return Cypress.Blob.canvasToBlob(canvas)
      .then(blob => Cypress.Blob.blobToArrayBuffer(blob))
      .then(buff => {
        const view = new Int8Array(buff);
        const buffer = Buffer.from(view);
        return buffer;
      })
  })
  return Promise.all(bufferPromises).then(buffers => {
    const bufferMap = new Map();
    buffers.forEach((buffer, i) => {
      // get coords here
      const coords = 1000 + i // for purpose of demo
      bufferMap.set(coords, buffer)
    })
    return bufferMap;
  })
});
```

Comment: hmm, looks like a working solution. Thanks a lot, I will try it asap. And I need exactly a map, to sort it in mergeImages task, sort them and after this get by bunches to firstly form the rows and after that merge them to the single image (column). How in your case I can firstly sort them and after get by index?

Comment: If you can show how you sort with Map I can translate to same for an object. So did you have the problem of passing the Map to the task? It's quite strange.

Comment: I don’t try it yet. I wrote comparator, that sort my entries in special order. And then const sorted = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => compare(a, b))

Comment: I guess you can `Object.keys(bufferObject).sort((a, b) => comparator(a, b))` then iterate the keys in sorted order. It's not clear to me whats in coordinates, there are two values so is an array?

Comment: Yes! Only two values separated by space. I added comparator function to question

Comment: Ooh, it not works from my phone) So, I will try it later, and if it works - will inform you! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cheers, will get it tomorrow as it's evening here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now pretty good for me! But the problem is with Map object. It won't work in way needed for me. So, your idea with array of Objects was awesome! I'll post answer in a moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution!

Now it works pretty good for me. Code sample:

```
function convertCanvasMatrixToPictureCommand() {
  Cypress.Commands.add('renderCanvasMatrixToPng', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, writeTo) => {
    const imgArr = [];

    cy.wrap(subject)
      .each(canvas =>
        new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
          Cypress.Blob.canvasToBlob(canvas.get(0))
            .then(blob => Cypress.Blob.blobToArrayBuffer(blob))
            .then(arrayBuffer => {
              const coordinates = extract(canvas.attr('style'));
              imgArr.push({ id: coordinates, buffer: arrayBuffer });
              resolve(true);
            });
        }))
      .then(() => {
        cy.task('mergeImages', {
          imageArrayBuffers: imgArr,
          outputFolder: writeTo,
        });
      });
  });
}
```